# Is it possible to reuse a chrome instance between independent protractor tests?

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I'm using protractor to automate some fairly time sensitive tasks on a heavy angular site which takes around 15 seconds to load.

I would like to see if there is a way to keep the instance of chrome open (and the page loaded) between various tests in order to avoid the new load each time.

Comment: If they are tests for the same application/website, why are they split up?

Comment: Because they are contingent on external events which do not occur at fixed intervals.  ie an external event occurs and I then automate an action on the website.  Want to avoid having to wait for the slow load each time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Protractor is a nice tool, so does proper cleaning after itself. I.e. It [quits](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/ed955e56a839d7f69da43acb6755763220d3681d/lib/driverProviders/local.ts) the browser if it started it.

So in order to keep your browsers alive between sessions, and save the 5-15 seconds, you can ask Protractor to [attach to a browser session](https://medium.com/@cnishina/attaching-a-protractor-test-to-an-existing-selenium-session-931196936ae2), instead of creating a new browser session.

This can be done using the config object, or via the command line.

```
<!-- language: typescript -->
/** in your protractor.conf.js or similar config object*/
 
directConnect: undefined,  // can be omitted, but just to show that directConnnect must not be set
seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
seleniumSessionId: '<your session id - 32 char hex code>',
```

However, starting a browser instance or finding a browser instance is not easy. It can be done using the [Selenium Standalone Console](http://localhost:4444/wd/hub) available at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub, assuming that you have selenium running.

See the [Webdriver-Reuse-Session](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webdriver-reuse-session) NPM package for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Can you, with certainty, say that these events wont occur simultaneously? If they do, your test results will be inconsistent. The reason that Protractor opens a new browser window each time, is to provide you with a clean start each time. This will ensure your tests run the exact same way each time.

Now, as for the solution:

In your `conf.js` file, you are specifying a browser to use (in your case Google Chrome). It probably looks along the lines of :

```
exports.config = {
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  specs: ['myspec.js'],
  capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome'
  }
};
```

As documented [here](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/browser-setup.md), you can add chrome-specific options to your capabilities such as `show-fps-counter`, `--start-maximized` and `--user-data-dir`. A full list of arguments can be found [here](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/). (It's a long one)

What you will need to add is:

```
capabilities: {
  'browserName': 'chrome',
  'chromeOptions': {
    'args': ['--user-data-dir=/your/path/of/choice']
  }
}
```

Your path of choice on Windows can be `--user-data-dir=c:\foo` for example.
On unix-based OS's `--user-data-dir=/usr/foo`

The `--user-data-dir` flag will force Chrome to store user data (Cookies, cached data, history and bookmarks). [Here](https://www.chromium.org/user-experience/user-data-directory) are the docs for it.

It will not leave the browser session open (which isn't ideal anyway), but it should greatly increase your performance as it will use cached data left by the previous test runs.

Don't be daunted when the first test still runs slowly, the first test won't have anything cached yet :).

Comment: Thanks Tom you're right, storing user data does make a big difference to speed and also has the benefit of avoiding to have to login each time which makes a difference in my tests.  I had already implemented that and was hoping to keep the window open as well :).  Any other ideas?